# Electron App Installation with Squirrel to ProgramFiles(x86)

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-packager, squirrel.windows

Does Squirrel support an Electron app installation to ProgramFiles(x86) ?

If yes, could you please explain me how it is done with an Electron app ?

I could not find anything about it. I have done the installation to %localappdata% yet. But it is very important for me that it can be installed to ProgramFiles(x86).

I did the installation with this guide: [Set Up Continuous Deployment on Electron Using Squirrel](http://www.theodo.fr/blog/2017/05/set-up-continuous-deployment-on-electron-using-squirrel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squirrel does not support it on Windows. It always installs in %localappdata%.

[See here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/605)